# Deleting a Collection - affect on documents within the collection

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I am using the Python Client to permanently delete collections (not move into trash but permanently delete).

The version of python gdata is 2.0.16.

Here is the code that I am using to permanently delete a collection:

```
        delimited = folder_entry.GetEditLink().href.split('?')
        url = delimited[0] + '?delete=true'
        client.Delete(url, force=True)
```

The issue that I am experiencing is what happens to the documents that were inside the collection that is being deleted.

This API used to (up until about the beginning of April 2012) not delete the documents that were inside the collection.  The end result would simply be that the documents that were inside the deleted collection would be 'untagged' from the collection.

Currently, this API work completely different in terms of the documents located inside the deleted collection.  Now, the documents inside the deleted collection will also be permanently deleted.

A few questions...

1) Is this change to the API expected?
2) Is there a new way to permanently delete a collection and simply 'untag' the documents that were located in that collection.

Thank you for any information.

- Dan

Answer (score 0):

I think this has less to do with how the API behaves but with how the whole product behaves.

With the move from Google Docs to Google Drive we've moved from collections used as "tags" to collections being "folders" and now, when deleting a folder, all the contained files are also deleted. The API reflects that behavior as a side-effect it seems.

Unfortunately I don't think much more work will be done on the Document List API as we are hard at work on the next version of the Drive API which should cover most of its features.